# Grabbing calculated latXlong distances in different rows and columns in matrix layout

Tags: loops, if-statement, pipe, distance, conditional-formatting

Problem

I have data with latitude and longitude coordinates that I calculated distance of each observation from the first starting point. I get a matrix when I calculate the distance that I can convert to a data frame. From there, I need to grab only one distance value but that value moves one column and one row.

Original Data

```
structure(list(latitude = c(38.4839693048603, 38.4839676888751, 
38.484000841, 38.4840256406904, 38.4842629760156, 38.4849478163079
), longitude = c(-123.055495022123, -123.055491287216, -123.055793254511, 
-123.056350426841, -123.05700151085, -123.057715977783)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

After calculating distances, converting units to ft

```
structure(list(V1 = structure(c(0, 1.21865987279359, 85.9395893412895, 
245.140367411948, 443.345616384121, 727.792251173584), units = structure(list(
    numerator = "ft", denominator = character(0)), class = "symbolic_units"), class = "units"), 
    V2 = structure(c(1.21865987279359, 0, 87.076605103043, 246.25311887669, 
    444.523156907811, 729.010874767996), units = structure(list(
        numerator = "ft", denominator = character(0)), class = "symbolic_units"), class = "units"), 
    V3 = structure(c(85.9395893412895, 87.076605103043, 0, 159.368289208323, 
    358.047418709711, 648.709228910322), units = structure(list(
        numerator = "ft", denominator = character(0)), class = "symbolic_units"), class = "units"), 
    V4 = structure(c(245.140367411948, 246.25311887669, 159.368289208323, 
    0, 205.10072777621, 515.020408170641), units = structure(list(
        numerator = "ft", denominator = character(0)), class = "symbolic_units"), class = "units"), 
    V5 = structure(c(443.345616384121, 444.523156907811, 358.047418709711, 
    205.10072777621, 0, 322.563054256646), units = structure(list(
        numerator = "ft", denominator = character(0)), class = "symbolic_units"), class = "units"), 
    V6 = structure(c(727.792251173584, 729.010874767996, 648.709228910322, 
    515.020408170641, 322.563054256646, 0), units = structure(list(
        numerator = "ft", denominator = character(0)), class = "symbolic_units"), class = "units"), 
    V7 = structure(c(1018.50792414677, 1019.71647638936, 943.971774385934, 
    819.591063850584, 631.321251450188, 308.865461805431), units = structure(list(
        numerator = "ft", denominator = character(0)), class = "symbolic_units"), class = "units"), 
    V8 = structure(c(1191.19804190322, 1192.4014434649, 1117.85419293343, 
    995.173866175853, 806.723702197458, 484.163222522177), units = structure(list(
        numerator = "ft", denominator = character(0)), class = "symbolic_units"), class = "units")), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

| V1 | V2 | V3 | V4 | V5 | V6 | V7 | V8 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **0.0000** | 1.21866 | 85.93959 | 245.1404 | 443.3426 | 727.7923 | 1018.5079 | 1191.1980 |
| **1.21866** | 0.0000 | 87.07661 | 246.2531 | 444.5232 | 729.0109 | 1019.7165 | 1192.4014 |
| 85.93959 | **87.07661** | 0.0000 | 159.3683 | 358.0474 | 648.7092 | 943.9718 | 1117.8542 |
| 245.14037 | 246.253 | **159.368** | 0.0000 | 205.100 | 515.024 | 819.591 | 995.1739 |
| 443.345 | 444.523 | 358.047 | **205.100** | 0.0000 | 322.563 | 631.321 | 806.723 |
| 727.792 | 729.010 | 648.709 | 515.020 | **322.563** | 0.0000 | 308.865 | 484.163 |
| 1018.507 | 1019.716 | 943.971 | 819.591 | 631.321 | **308.865** | 0.0000 | 175.726 |
| 1191.1198 | 1192.401 | 1117.854 | 995.173 | 806.723 | 484.1632 | **175.726** | 0.0000 |

I want to pull into a new column, 8 observations, being:
1: [1,V1]
2. [2,V1]
3. [3,V2]
4. [4,V3]
5. [5,V4]
and so on... so that I get 8 distances with the first being 0 as the start position and the following after are the distance from that starting point.

Answer (score 0):

```
pacman::p_load(tidyverse, sf)

d <- 
tibble(latitude = c(38.4839693048603, 38.4839676888751, 
                    38.484000841, 38.4840256406904, 
                    38.4842629760156, 38.4849478163079),
       longitude = c(-123.055495022123, -123.055491287216, 
                     -123.055793254511, -123.056350426841, 
                     -123.05700151085, -123.057715977783) ) %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("longitude", "latitude"), crs = 4326) %>%
  st_transform(26910) 
  
res = tibble() 
for(i in 1:(nrow(d)-1) ) { # go up to the second-to-last row
  d1 = slice(d, i) # get a start point
  d2 = slice(d, i + 1) # get an end point

  dX = st_distance(d1, d2, by_element = TRUE) # distance between start and end
  
  tibble(start = d1, 
         stop = d2, 
         dist = dX) %>%
    bind_rows(res, .) -> res
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.